# Button inside fxml file does not in the ObservableMap returned by fxmlLoader.getNamespace()

Tags: javafx-2

I have the following code to load the fxml file. I want to change the width of the button. I am able to access the two labels using `fxmlLoader.getNamespace().get("id")`, but for some reason I don't see the button inside `ObservableMap` returned by `getNamespace()`. Why is it so/

**FXML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<GridPane fx:controller="org.netbeans.modules.mavenproject1.controller.KeyController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    <padding>
        <Insets top="5" right="5" bottom="5" left="5"/>
    </padding>
    <children>
        <Button maxHeight="45.0" maxWidth="45.0" minHeight="45.0" minWidth="45.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="45.0" style="" styleClass="alphabet-button" text="~" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="ELLIPSIS">
            <graphic>
                <GridPane alignment="TOP_LEFT">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="1" right="1" bottom="1" left="1"/>
                    </padding>
                    <children>
                        <Label text="" fx:id="mainTextLabel" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                        <Label text="" fx:id="shiftTextLabel" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                    </children>
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="20.0" prefWidth="20.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="20.0" prefWidth="20.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="20.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="20.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>
            </graphic>
            <stylesheets>
                <URL value="@../styles/keyboard.css" />
            </stylesheets>
        </Button>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

**Controller Constructor**

```
 public Key(){
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/key.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>(){
        @Override
        public Object call(Class<?> param){
            return keyController = new KeyController();
        }
    });

    try {            
        keyView = (Node) fxmlLoader.load();            
    } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
    mainTextLabel = (Label) fxmlLoader.getNamespace().get("mainTextLabel");
    shiftTextLabel = (Label) fxmlLoader.getNamespace().get("shiftTextLabel");

    getChildren().add(keyView);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this as a wiki post. I found the solution by trial and error ( seems like the best way to learn programming ), but if somebody can show me a location on oracle docs where the following detail is listed, you have my upvote.

**Answer**

Just add fx:id to the button.

***Before***

`<Button maxHeight="45.0" maxWidth="45.0" minHeight="45.0" minWidth="45.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="45.0" style="" styleClass="alphabet-button" text="~" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="ELLIPSIS">`

***After***

`<Button fx:id="button" maxHeight="45.0" maxWidth="45.0" minHeight="45.0" minWidth="45.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="45.0" style="" styleClass="alphabet-button" text="~" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="ELLIPSIS">`